# Gulp/webpack css specificity remover

Tags: webpack, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, css-specificity

Hey we have a load of legacy 6 years old css built with sass.

Unfortunately over the year people went a little mad with it all and now we have sass with 15 levels of specificity. This has meant our compiled compressed CSS is enormous.

As we are about to embark on a complete rebuild of our site in redux, management don't want to spend the resources to clean up our CSS which is understandable.

What I was wondering as a quick fix is there a plug in for gulp/webpack that could programmatically clean up the specificity where not needed as part of the build pipeline?

Comment: Postcss is the tool to go, i've managed to find [`postcss-increase-specificity`][1] u can try to write the decrease one, with the usage of https://www.npmjs.com/package/specificity 


  [1]: https://github.com/MadLittleMods/postcss-increase-specificity

Comment: BTW, this is not such a trivial problem to solve, think about what should append if there is `div > div > div > div`, you are not allowed to change that.

Answer (score 2):

I've wrote something that should help with that problem :].
https://github.com/felixmosh/postcss-decrease-specificity

This postcss plugin reduces the amount of decented class selectors that are nested more then `options.depth` (defaults to 3).

This plugin supports several scenarios:

- `.a .b .c .d` -> `.b .c .d`
- `tag .a .b .c .d` -> `tag .b .c .d`
- `#id .a .b .c .d` -> `#id .b .c .d`
- `.a .b > .c` -> `.a .b > .c`
- `.a .b .c .d .e > .f` -> `.c .d .e > .f`

For more supported cases checkout the [tests](https://github.com/felixmosh/postcss-decrease-specificity/blob/master/index.spec.js).

I know that this plugin is not covering all the cases, and it is not perfect, but with PR's we can make it more suitable.

⚠️ Use this plugin with caution, it may break your design.

Comment: Awesome I'm going to try this on our site tonight